# What is the maximum time length of a download on Google AppEngine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'd like to schedule a download of streaming media to run at given times, for about 20 minutes at a time. Is this possible with AppEngine (Python)? The [URL Fetch](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview#Quotas_and_Limits) docs suggest that the limit is 60 seconds, but is there a way to do this without using the URL Fetch API?

Comment: Downloading a file and streaming media are different operations, can you provide an example on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: perhaps look at Amazons alternative. you get a "pc in the cloud" with no timeout limits etc.

Comment: I'm currently using Rackspace; I'd like to move to AppEngine for other reasons.

I have an m3u file that's active at certain times in the day, and I'd like to record what's playing at those times. Currently I have a bash script that lets mplayer do that, but I'd like to find a way to do so on AppEngine if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to use a backend to do that as backends can run indefinitely although exactly which functions you would use would be dependant on what you were streaming.